# graph api profile feed (wall) show fake feeds id :(

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

[image]
 [image]

```
$profile_feed= $facebook->api("/me/feed?limit=4" . $access_token );    
foreach($profile_feed['data'] as $profile_feed) {
     echo "<p> " . $profile_feed['id'] . "</p>";
     echo "<p> " . $profile_feed['message'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked it using the Graph API explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: thx for replay :)...yes... ihave... this is url apps  
hxxp://apps.metamorfoself.com/alittleheart/profile_feed.php

Comment: Are you getting this problem for only selected ID's or all the ID's ?

Comment: id and name and the same problem fetch friend feed ...

Comment: can you show any ID's that are fake ?

Comment: 100003244834577_154116488039845 thats an id nothing post... and i try using api explorer thats id is nothing.. can u check the link hxxp://apps.metamorfoself.com/alittleheart/profile_feed.php?

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug at [http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? :

```
$profile_feed= $facebook->api("/me/feed?limit=4" . $access_token );    
foreach($profile_feed['data'] as $data) {
    echo "<p> " . $data['from']['name'] .  " with ID " . $data['from']['id'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p> " . $data['message'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: thats code iam trying to show an id and message ( check my wrong code ) i think my wrong is use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/    thats reference not same with graph api explorer ( not show data story ) and now the problem is solved many thx for all replay..